# why subprocess.terminate doesn't work when I use a variable?

Tags: python

```
current_process = None
async def player():
    global current_process

    if current_process:
        current_process.terminate()
  
    # other code here 

    current_process = subprocess.Popen('start python player.py', shell=True)
```

I don't get why `current_process.terminate()` is not working, there aren't errors

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - a full short program demonstrating the error. I'm guessing you are not waiting on your processes to complete.

Comment: `start` launches the specified program, *and then exits* - after a fraction of a second, there won't be anything to terminate.  You should run `python player.py` directly if you want to control its execution.

Comment: I already tried without `start` but nothing changed, btw [this](https://mystb.in/CommMaternitySlide.python) is the full code